# PHP - why fopen() does not work in the registered "register_shutdown_function"?

Tags: php

the `fopen()` fails and it outputs

> Warning: fopen(logs/response_rowbody/230.mlog): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 5

after hours of isolating the reasons that might be causing the problem, I found it is because the function is called in function registered with `register_shutdown_function` . and I don't know if this is normal or not!

this is the code that I use

#### this code works

the file C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php

```
<?php
//register_shutdown_function('logresponse'); 
/*the function logresponse() works here because it has been called naturaly at the end of the file without being shut_down_registered*/
logresponse();
function logresponse(){
   $response_rowbody = "logs/response_rowbody/230.mlog";
   $fhandle = fopen($response_rowbody,"wb");if(!$fhandle){echo"errorrr";};
exit;};
?>
```

#### this code does not work

the file C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php

```
<?php
register_shutdown_function('logresponse'); 
/*the function logresponse() does NOT work here because it has been called as a shut-down registered function*/
//logresponse();
function logresponse(){
   $response_rowbody = "logs/response_rowbody/230.mlog";
   $fhandle = fopen($response_rowbody,"wb");if(!$fhandle){echo"errorrr";};
exit;};
?>
```

what am I doing wrong here??
*thanks.*

Comment: On the Windows platform, be careful to escape any backslashes used in the path to the file, or use forward slashes.

Comment: @PatrickMlr thanks for your interest. but I don't think this is the problem in my case because the same file path works in the first code(without `register_shutdown_function`)

Comment: Maybe you have to adjust the path to a static path. Like `c:\\folder\\resource.txt`

Comment: @PatrickMlr thanks. absolute path worked in the both examples!!  but why?

Comment: I'll write an answer, so other can see that you got it. Just remember to accept it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you have to adjust the path to a static path. Like `c:\\folder\\resource.txt`

Answer (score 1):

From [the manual](http://php.net/register_shutdown_function):

> Working directory of the script can change inside the shutdown
>   function under some web servers, e.g. Apache.

That means you cannot trust relative paths. Use absolute paths instead.